# Construct a CFG for $L = \{ w \in \{0,1\}^*\text{ } |\text{ } w = w^R \text{ and } |w| \text{ is even}\}$

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

I need to construct a CFG for the following language$$L = \{ w \in \{0,1\}^*\text{ } |\text{ } w = w^R \text{ and } |w| \text{ is even}\}$$

I know that the two middle position should always be the same. E.g. $11,00,0\underline{11}0,0\underline{00}0,\dots$ Each position on the opposite sides of the middle points should also be the same.

So these are the production rules of the CFG I came up with
$$
S\rightarrow00$$
$$S\rightarrow11$$
$$S\rightarrow ASA$$
$$A\rightarrow1$$
$$A\rightarrow0$$
$$A\rightarrow \epsilon$$
Is this solution correct?

Comment: The structure of the grammar is OK, but the details are not. You can derive $S \Rightarrow ASA \Rightarrow^2 0S1 \Rightarrow \dots $

Comment: @HendrikJan I think I got it, I'll change my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [HendrikJan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4287/hendrik-jan) stated, we can for example obtain the following languages with above CFG
$$01, 0001,\dots$$
which do not meet the required conditions.

Instead, we need to make sure that the ends are always the same. We can do that by the following production rules.

$$
S\rightarrow 0S0$$
$$S\rightarrow 1S1$$
$$S\rightarrow \epsilon$$